# WCF supports SMB protocol? Or other protocols that does not necessarily run over TCP?

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, connection, smb

I have encountered some troubles connecting some different machines of mine to a dedicated Windows service that runs `WCF` (a listener).
Those machines have an external modem connected to them, which probably disturb `TCP` connection to the outside, but the machines should establish a connection via `WCF` with the aforementioned listener service.

Since all the connection I need is inside my network (different machines tough), and it seems that Windows Sharing (copying files, etc') **does** work, (assuming I am not mistaking and it uses the `SMB` protocol), I would prefer, if possible, to use that protocol, or other protocols that don't run over `TCP`, to have a working connection.
I could not find on MSDN any help, but maybe someone has tried something like that before, or has encountered similar problems, and can help me with a solution to that.

Some code (pretty generic I guess):

```
private const string ServiceEndointURL = "net.tcp://localhost:6789/MyService";
```

used under: `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, UseSynchronizationContext = true)]
    public class MyApplication : IService`
where `IService` is defined:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "MyService")]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool HandleMessage(Message message);
}
```

Other side ("client"):

```
string ListenerURL = "net.tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:6789/MyService";
        ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>
            (new MyNetBindings(), ListenerURL );
        IService channel = l_oFactory.CreateChannel();
        ((IContextChannel)channel).OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 1);
```

EDIT:
It seems that the external modem is taking the place of the default gateway on that machine, which is probably the cause for no connection.
When manually adding a persistent route, with the original gateway (with low metrics) - it seems to be working again. Any way to automatically work around it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So... `SMB` is not a transport protocol. `SMB` itself mostly uses `TCP`, but it can also run on `UDP`. If you want to use `WCF` over `UDP` you can (more [info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163648.aspx#S8)), but i doubt that will work better for you.

My guess is that you have a specific problem with `WCF` or your network, and you should try to fix that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
As I've read (on Wikipedia), it might indeed run on different transport layers. Maybe I am mixing things, my understanding is not deep regarding this stuff. But the fact is that copying files to other machines works fine, with the external modem connected, while WCF over TCP does not.
I don't know why and don't know if Im in the right direction of solving it, so i'd be glad to receive more ideas on how I can solve it.
Thanks

Comment: @AndroidNewbie You should probably ask a question and show your WCF configuration, the code you're using and the error details you get.

Comment: @AndroidNewbie a new question would have been better.